# Самопроизвольное отключение мышки

Tags: linux, ubuntu, железо, ноутбук, мышь

На ноутбуке самопроизвольно отключается мышка.

Происходит это как во время работы, так и после выхода ноутбука из режима сна. Однако после перезагрузки мышь возобновляет работу. Операционная система — Ubuntu 14.04.

В чем может быть проблема, и как ее исправить?

Comment: *нужно перезагружать* — отключить/подключить кабель, которым подключен манипулятор, будет, вероятно, быстрее.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/80638/416190

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, если так делать, даже подключать в другие разъемы - никакого результата до перезагрузки системы!

Comment: открой терминал, напиши tail -f /var/log/syslog  и работай, пока мышь не отвалится, потом переключись туда и посмотри в ошибки, после этого нагугли ошибку. можешь попробовать усыпить-разбудить комп, но тебе будет труднее найти нужное сообщение об ошибке

Comment: У меня на бунтах и основанных мышь (внешняя, usb) временами перезапускалась (редко, была отключена 1 секунду).

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо за отклики, решить проблему мне помог комментарий [alexander barakin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178576/alexander-barakin). Сделал [так](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80638/how-to-disable-auto-power-off-of-usb-devices-like-usb-mouse)  и мышь работает нормально и больше не отключалась!

Comment: По сути не является ответом. Ссылка на вопрос с несколькими ответами, и не понятно в итоге, что именно помогло.

Answer (score 1):

Бывало такое, провод мышиный переламывался и мышь начинала глючить. Проверить можно подключив временно другую мышь.
Иногда можно проверить наличие её работы по свечению датчика под мышью.

Comment: датчик работает и мышь тоже, подключал к другому компьютеру

Comment: 1. Предлагал другую мышь попробовать. 2. Провод у основания мыши погните, не отваливается при этом мышь?

Comment: с любой мышью одинаково

Comment: @Maybe_V Значит в Вашем случае, проблема в железе компьютера или в ОС.